# Sequentially Compact of a closed ball in $l^p$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider a $l^p$-space and define a closed ball in $l^p$ as

$$\bar B:=\left\{\{a_n\}_n: \sum_n^\infty |a_n|^p \le 1 \right\}$$

I was wondering why $\bar B$ is NOT sequentially compact?

(Definition for sequentially compact: for every sequence in $\bar B$ has a convergent subsequence).

I don't see why this is true.
For example, if I pick $\{0,1,0,0,...\} \in \bar{B}$ or $\{1,0,0,0,...\}\in \bar{B}$ or $\{0,0,1,0,0,...\}\in \bar{B}$, I still can make a corresponding convergent subsequence like $\{0,0,0,0,...\}$. and this trick seems work for any sequence in $\bar B$..

Comment: !by Riez theorem (and  $l^p$ has infinite dimension)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ where $e_n=\delta_{nm}$ cannot have convergent subsequences. Since $\|e_n-e_m\|_p=2^{1/p}$ for all $n\ne m$.

To clarify last point, every convergent sequence is Cauchy so the norm of the differences must go to zero in any convergence sequence.

Comment: Thanks, @azarel, I know $||e_n - e_m||_p = 2^{1/p}$ but I still not very clear about why this make $\{e_n\}$ don't have convergent subsequences? Could you say more word about this point?

Comment: @Fianra I added some details.

Comment: Thank you, @azarel, since the $l^p$-norm equals to $2^{1/p}$ with $\infty>p>0$, hence the $||e_n - e_m||$ not go to zero, hence it is Not Cauchy, hence not convergent sequence? Am I saying this way right?

Comment: @Fianra Correct.